How do you insert an interval into a disjoint segment tree in Haskell?
I don't think this is standard terminology, but we will define a "disjoint segment tree" as a segment tree (a flavor of binary search tree) whose values are pairwise-separated intervals (a,b) where a <= b, representing blocks of time. I use the word "separated" to disallow adjacent intervals.
I want to write a function to insert an interval into such a tree, preserving the data invariant by merging any overlapping or adjacent intervals. However, I can't figure out what to do in the case where the interval being inserted overlaps with the root interval (see the undefineds below).
Here is a partial solution:
data SegTree = Empty | Node (Int, Int) SegTree SegTree deriving (Eq, Show)

-- | Whether an interval ends strictly before another interval.
isStrictlyBefore :: (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int) -> Bool
(_, b1) `isStrictlyBefore` (a2, _) = b1 < a2

combine :: (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int)
combine (a1,b1) (a2,b2) = (min a1 a2, max b1 b2)

-- | Insert an interval into a segment tree by merging touching intervals.
insertByMerge :: (Int, Int) -> SegTree -> SegTree
insertByMerge x' Empty  = Node x' Empty Empty
insertByMerge x' (Node x l r)
  | x' `isStrictlyBefore` x  = Node x (insertByMerge x' l) r
  | x  `isStrictlyBefore` x' = Node x l (insertByMerge x' r)
  | otherwise = Node undefined undefined undefined
  where
    l' = insertByMerge (combine x x') l
    r' = insertByMerge (combine x x') r

Any pointers?

What exactly does the node interval represent, compared to the intervals from its two children?

I have edited the question to make this clearer. We can say they are blocks of time. The tree is just an ordered collection of events.

So the interval of an inner node must lie between the last interval of its left child and the first interval of its right child? Or does it need to encompass them (so that you can quickly search the tree)? And do you have any tree invariants, like balancing requirements?

The former. Encompassing would be disallowed as the intervals must be disjoint, if I'm understanding you correctly. No balancing requirements. However I'm looking for something better than "convert to list" and "convert back to degenerate solely-left-branching tree".

In case of overlap, do you want the insertion to fail (for example by returning Nothing) or to merge the overlapping intervals?

You probably want two functions trimRight and trimLeft, both Int -> SegTree -> (SegTree, Int). The functions should return the trimmed tree where all intervals are strictly to the right (resp. left) of the integer, and the new integer is the max (resp min) of the old ineger and all the removed intervals. If your interval overlaps the root, you trim the children and combine the root with the results.

@Li-yao Xia In the case of overlap, I want to merge the overlapping intervals.
